# using logical expression in arcpy

Tags: python, where-clause, arcgis, arcpy

I am trying to write a python command that includes a logical query. I have series of tables and layers and would like to run a command on them when two shared variables have the same values. I created a list of those tables and layers:

```
pattern = '*Assess*.dbf'
files = []
tables = []
layernames = []
## create the loop element
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in arcpy.da.Walk(inputFolder):
    # append shapefile path to list
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, pattern):
        files.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))

tables = arcpy.ListTables()

for file in files:
    names.append("\"TOWN_ID\" = " + str(int(os.path.basename(file).rstrip(os.path.splitext(file)[1])[1:4])))
    layernames.append(str(int(os.path.basename(file).rstrip(os.path.splitext(file)[1])[1:4])))
```

The code is as followed:

```
for layername, table in zip(layernames, tables):
    #print layername
    #print table
    #CF_QueryTool = "C:\\ArcGIS_Temp\\parcel_mosaic\\land_parcels_mosaic.gdb\\cf_QueryTool"
    tablelist = [table, "TaxParcels_Layer.{}".format(layername)]
    wherecluase = "TaxParcels_Layer.{}.LOC_ID = table.LOC_ID".format(layername)
    print tablelist
    print wherecluase
    arcpy.MakeQueryTable_management(tablelist, "QueryTable.{}".format(layername), "ADD_VIRTUAL_KEY_FIELD", "", "" ,wherecluase)
    print "QueryTable.{} created".format(layername)
```

The problem is, apparently there is something wrong with my wherecluase which made me wonder if I can actually use something like table.locid using a list of tables. Let me know if I'm making a mistake here. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Since "table" is both a SQL reserved keyword and invalid name within a file geodatabase (*.gdb), I assume you want the value of the variable `table` in your SQL WHERE clause and not the word "table."  You need to add another argument specifier to your `whereclause` formatting:

```
>>> table = "myTable"
>>> layername = "myLayer"
>>> 
>>> # original code
>>> whereclause = "TaxParcels_Layer.{}.LOC_ID = table.LOC_ID".format(layername)
>>> print(whereclause)
TaxParcels_Layer.myLayer.LOC_ID = table.LOC_ID
>>> 
>>> # modified code
>>> whereclause = "TaxParcels_Layer.{}.LOC_ID = {}.LOC_ID".format(layername, table)
>>> print(whereclause)
TaxParcels_Layer.myLayer.LOC_ID = myTable.LOC_ID
>>>
```